# Trouble with mysql subquery

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with the following values: Name, Street,I'd , Value, Date.

I need to combine Name, Street, Id and make 2 subgroups by date. I want to compare the value in row with the same name, street and id but different date. And write only the ones with different value

Example:

Mike, Street 1 , idtag , 5 , 11.5.2022

Mike, street 1 , idtag , 10 , 10.5.2022

I want to write the difference in value with the name, street, id combination.

All the solutions I have tried take way to long

Comment: Do you understand that when you have 31 rows for `Mike, Street 1, idtag` for a month where all dates and values differs then you'll obtain ~900 pairs in the output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

dYou could use an aggregation approach here.  Assuming that you want to flag any name, street, and ID combination which have 2 or more records on different dates, you may try:

```sql
SELECT name, street, ID, MAX(val) - MIN(val) AS diff
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY name, street, ID
HAVING MIN(date) <> MAX(date);
```

To use this logic for a specific pair of records, whose (unique) date values are known, use this version:

```sql
SELECT name, street, ID, MAX(val) - MIN(val) AS diff
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY name, street, ID
HAVING MIN(date) = '2022-05-10' AND MAX(date) = '2022-05-11';
```

Comment: This works very well. Thank you. My only question is how would you define specific dates. For example if I want the difference between 10.5.2022 and 11.5.2022?

Comment: Well, if you just want to _report_ the two dates, you could include in the select `MIN(date)` and `MAX(date)`.

Comment: I mean the current statement prints the difference between min and max date value how can I test for 2 specific dates and get dif instead of min and max date